# Pandas dataframe selection based on content of list object in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection

I have a pandas dataframe where one column contains list objects which gives me `dtype: object.` The list objects are of different lengths.

```
        features           other_features
0        ["foo", "bar"]                2
1        ["foo", "dog"]                1
2        ["dog"]                       4
```

I want to select the rows in my dataframe where the list has elements that are in a different list `external_list = ["dog", "cat"]`.

In this case I would like the result to be the rows that contains dog or cat together with the other coulmns, which would be:

```
        features           other_features
1        ["foo", "dog"]                1
2        ["dog"]                       4
```

I have tried isin, but from what I understand it requires the column type of the element to look at to not be a list of more than one object.

`filter = df["features"].isin(["dog", "cat"])`

It results in every element being False, which it should not since some should be True, and it is not returning the rest of the columns.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` with comparing list converted to sets tested by `isdisjoint`, `~` is for inverse mask:

```
#if string repr of list
#import ast
#df['features'] = df['features'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

external_list = ["dog", "cat"]
df = df[~df.features.map(set(external_list).isdisjoint)]
print (df)
     features  other_features
1  [foo, dog]               1
2       [dog]               4
```

Comment: Thank you! At first the resulting data frame was empty, the comments with literal_eval solved it and it gives me exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let us do "explode" on axis =0, then we can do `isin`

```
m=pd.DataFrame(df.features.tolist(),index=df.index).isin(external_list).any(1)
df=df[~m]
```